# Dart - How to delete element in JSON

Tags: json, dart

How can i delete an element in json in dart? For example, i want to delete the id element.

```
{
    "activityPostId":"fc4bc183-e71a-47a2-8fcd-a1eb229148b6",
    "netUserId":"ca2e7f96-8d91-4195-9fa6-69e13e9d33c5",
    "quantity":"1",
    "price":"18.0",
    "reserveOnly":null,
    "comments":null,
    "id":null,
}
```

Comment: So to clarify, is this a JSON string or a `Map<String, dynamic>` that you want to modify?

Comment: yes. i need to remove it before i submit it to api

Comment: That doesn't answer the question...

Answer (score 5):

I assume that your example is that you are initializing a Map that you will encode to JSON like:

```
final data = {
    "activityPostId":"fc4bc183-e71a-47a2-8fcd-a1eb229148b6",
    "netUserId":"ca2e7f96-8d91-4195-9fa6-69e13e9d33c5",
    "quantity":"1",
    "price":"18.0",
    "reserveOnly":null,
    "comments":null,
    "id":null,
}
```

Since this is just a Map under the hood.. its as simple as:

```
data.remove('id');
```

Then to serialize of course:

```
json.encode(data);
```